# GUID in JAVA can Contain Space?

Tags: java, guid

I want to know about GUID in JAVA. GUID can contain a white space or not?

i am using following Code

```
import java.util.UUID;

UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
```

`randomUUIDString` can contain White Space? if yes what is chances to avoid it ?

Comment: I want concat some other string with randomUUIDString with this and further i want to split cancat string again

Comment: See RFC for [UUID](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) and check whether it can contain a space.

Comment: Are you asking or telling?  What makes you think that `UUID.randomUUID()` would return whitespaces?

Comment: i am asking it having whit space or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. From the documentation of [`UUID.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString%28%29)

> The UUID string representation is as described by this BNF:
>
> ```
>    UUID                   = <time_low> "-" <time_mid> "-"
>                              <time_high_and_version> "-"
>                              <variant_and_sequence> "-"
>                              <node>
>     time_low               = 4*<hexOctet>
>     time_mid               = 2*<hexOctet>
>     time_high_and_version  = 2*<hexOctet>
>     variant_and_sequence   = 2*<hexOctet>
>     node                   = 6*<hexOctet>
>     hexOctet               = <hexDigit><hexDigit>
>     hexDigit               =
>           "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
>           | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f"
>           | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F"
> ```

As you can see, every character in the returned string will be a character from A-F, a-f, 0-9 or '-'.

Comment: Yes, sorry i haven't see last line.

Comment: @SwapL only characters present in hexadecimal numbers and - sign will be present. Also have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form